# Search for string in dangling commits in Git

Tags: git, git-dangling

The following monstrosity very nicely found a git stash containing the word Upload which is what I was looking for:

```
git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' | \
while read ref; do if [ "`git show -p $ref|grep -c Upload`" -ne 0 ]; then echo $ref ; fi ; done
```

Is there a prettier version of this? I guess the pickaxe should work but `git log -g` doesn't see this commit.

Comment: Did you try `git log -g -p`?

Comment: Sure, it doesn't work -- again, `git log -g` doesn't list the 'winning' commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... but `git log -g` doesn't see this commit

Commits that are (still) referenced by the reflog are considered reachable and not dangling. Thus running `git log –g` is contrary to what you wanted, so no surprises here.

Commits will be reachable via reflog for the gc.reflogExpire timespan, with a default of 90 days.

> Is there a prettier version of this?

No, `git fsck` is the right way for accessing dangling commits.

Comment: OK, so `git fsck` is the right way for the first half. Then, given a list of commits, is there a better way to search in them?

Comment: @chx I don't believe so, since the commits are dangling. You cannot rely on git walking any trees rooted in those commits for your stead with something like `git log --grep=Upload`, and thus have to process each commit individually yourself.

Comment: I ended up doing this:

`git fsck --no-reflog | awk '/dangling commit/ {print $3}' | xargs -n1 git log -p -1 > commits.txt
`

To at least get a single file of all the code contained in the dangling commits.